# How to simulate a network (connection) error with CGI

Tags: perl

My CGI script uses headers `Content-Disposition: attachment` and `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, so I am printing a file content in chunks.

Because the content depends on many factors and it is generated real-time, in some scenarios the script cannot finish its work. If that happen, the partial content that has been sent is invalid file. If script ends regular way, web server close connection and browser accept the content as complete and offers user to save or open downloaded file, even it is invalid.

I am looking for solution how to simulate a network error or anything similar that would lead to some error, so browser would not believe that download has been successfully completed and will not offer client to save or open such file.

Comment: Interesting question.  Script errors are usually conveyed to the browser by way of HTTP headers, but what makes this challenging is that most browsers will not recognize headers after content has already been sent.

As another way of doing this, can your script buffer all the content on the server side (either in memory are in a temporary file), until you are sure that you have all of the content, then only send the entire content to the browser once you know that it is intact?

Comment: @mti2935 - Correct! Even specification for `chunked` encoding allows headers to be present also after content at the end of file, major browsers have not implemented this feature yet. As of your second part of comment - in my case, content cannot be cached or delayed and needs to be sent as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you testing on the client side or the CGI?

Comment: @Ωmega I mean are you testing the browser's handling of the error, or the server side handling of the error when a client breaks the connection?

Comment: @chooban - Client does not break connection. You misunderstand my question. Read it again...

Comment: Yes, I was confused by your initial response of "yes". Anyway, I'll post my suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one way to do this is to cause your script to have a run-time error (such as a divide by zero error) if it runs into a situation where it cannot generate the remainder of the output.  I'm curious how the browser would respond in that case.

Comment: Unfortunately, even for `$_ = 1/0;` web server close connection regularly

Answer (score 0):

Since you're testing the behaviour of the client in the face of errors, the following might be suitable.

Create a simulator for your CGI which will accept an incoming connection, send some data back to the client and then sleep for *n* seconds before closing the connection. Then configure your client to have a timeout value of something less than *n*. At this point, your client code should suffer a timeout and enter the error handling code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully grasp the server logic in place here; but whenever I've had to mess with connections I typically use [`netem`](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#Delay_distribution) to introduce packet loss and/or delay (e.g. to trigger timeouts) -- YMMV.